# Get a field from SQL by another field

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Really new here hope this platform can help me..

I'm trying to build a plugin for wordpress and I'm in my early stages testing it before closing it into a plugin..

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
post_id, taxonomy1, taxonomy2
```

The taxonomies can be only a number between 1 and 3 (can be 0 but not likely)

In addition to that, I have a cookie stored somewhere with another value..

I need to write a function, that returns the post_id of the post in the row where taxonomy1 is equal to tax1 in the cookie, and taxonomy2 is tax2 in the cookie +1...

For example my cookies are 1 and 2.

I need to find the first row in the table, that the tax1 = 1, and the tax2 is = 3...

I think that should be really simple but I don't know how even to search for this...

Comment: Maybe [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/custom-taxonomy-wp-query-for-all-terms-in-a-taxonomy) could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your function would need to call the following SQL with the actual values passed in, of course:

```
select post_id from your_table
 where taxonomy1 = 1 and taxonomy2 = 3 order by post_id limit 1;
```

Assuming incrementing post_ids, this would only ever return the first post.  If you want the last post, you would change the order by clause:

```
select post_id from your_table
 where taxonomy1 = 1 and taxonomy2 = 3 order by post_id desc limit 1;
```

Comment: okay i got to this part.. now i have a problem in which im getting 1 instead of the post id.. :( also thank you so much for your help!

Comment: can you run the sql separately just to verify that's working using the mysql client or mysql workbench?  If you get the right value that way, then the problem is probably in your plugin code somewhere.

Comment: yeah it works :) just when im writing this inside the functions.php it returns 1 instead of 566 (the post id)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm less familiar with wordpress plugins, but feel free to post the plugin code you are using.  Maybe I can see something, but if not,  I'm sure someone else will know what to do.

Comment: okay.. i found the problem.. now im getting an array, instead of just the int of the post_id.. one step at a time :)

Comment: Cool.  Glad to help.